# Does bidding early on a project increases the rank of the bid on freelancer.in?

Tags: project-bidding

If a freelancer bids on a project as soon as it is opened on freelancer, does it increases the rank of that bid?

I have noticed this but I am not hundred percent sure. While viewing my bid insights I noticed a pattern that the bids which I made late on the project were ranked low, and the bids which were placed early were having higher ranks.

Comment: I think this is mainly because **clients think that freelancers who bid quickly will be quick to respond in the future**.<br>
There is a _sort by bid time function_, but it's not so important.<br>
The first thing I said is most important reason.

Answer (score 3):

Freelancer.com seems to avoid deliberately stating how their bid ranking algorithms work, but they do provide a [bid ranking guide](https://www.freelancer.com/community/articles/the-freelancer-com-bid-ranking-guide), written by [Emma D](https://www.freelancer.com/u/deHaaas), that gives you a set of tips to increase your chances of interacting with the employer. The *very first* tip they present is, with my emphasis on the important part:

> Bid Early: Can’t get to the top? Bid before the others do. Early bidders consistently win more projects since **it increases their chances of interacting with the employer**.

Couple this with the anecdotal experience you have with your late bids being ranked lower, and I think that we can safely say that early bidders *do* in fact get a boost to their bid's rank. Even if they don't, the increase in visibility granted to those who bid early is very certainly worth it.